# How do put two different arrays in one array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have two different arrays, name and score and I want to  put them in the same array so its [name:   , score:  ].

```
var allNames:Array = ["Test A", "Test B", "Test C"]; 
var allScores:Array = ["10","7","0"];**
```

For example it takes the first elements of each array and puts them together then the second and third ect. so the arrays above become

```
var NamesAndScore = [names:Test A score:10], [name:Test B score:7], [name:Test C score:0]
```

I'm sorry if this looks dumb since I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var allNames:Array = ["Test A", "Test B", "Test C"]; 
var allScores:Array = ["10","7","0"];

// Initialise a new array for the names and scores
var namesAndScores:Array = [];

for (var i:int = 0; i < allNames.length; i ++)
{
    // Push an object with name and score properties onto the new array
    namesAndScores.push({
        name: allNames[i],
        score: parseInt(allScores[i], 10)
    });
}

// To access the name and score properties of the first element of the new array
trace("name 1", namesAndScores[0].name, "score 1", namesAndScores[0].score);
```